# how to open mail composer using jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

i'm working on mobile app. on click of an image /button a mail compose should open,.
let me know if need to use any plugin.
pls help me on this, i'll be very greatful to you.
thanks in advance..

E-MAIL

### diagnose

From: